# running time for print out all primes under N

Tags: algorithm

```
int main() {
      int i, a[N];
      // initialize the array
      for(i = 2; i < N; i++) a[i] = 1;
      for(i = 2; i < N; i++)
         if(a[i])
              for(int j = i; j*i < N; j++) a[i*j] =0;
       // pirnt the primes less then N
       for(i = 2; i < N; i++)
           if(a[i]) cout << "  " << i;
       cout << endl;
}
```

It was given in algorithm book i am reading running time of above program is proportional to `N+N/2+N/3+N/5+N/7+N/11+...`,

Please help me in understanding how author came up with above equation from the program.
Thanks!
Venkata

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the "Sieve of Eratosthenes" method for finding primes. For each prime, the `if(a[i])` test succeeds and the inner loop gets executed. Consider how this inner loop terminates at each step (remember, the condition is `j*i < N`, or equivalently, `j < N/i`):

- i = 2 -> j = 2, 3, 4, ..., N/2
- i = 3 -> j = 3, 4, 5, ..., N/3
- i = 4 -> not prime
- i = 5 -> j = 5, 6, 7, ..., N/5
- ...

Summing the total number of operations (including initialising the array/extracting the primes) gives the runtime mentioned in the book.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2582732/time-complexity-of-sieve-of-eratosthenes-algorithm) for more, including a discussion of how, in terms of bit operations, this turns into an expansion of O(n(log n)(log log n)) as per the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes).

Comment: Thanks for the help. Now i understood how running time of the alogorithm is anlayzed.

Answer (score 1):

This algorithm is called the Sieve of Eratosthenes. This image explains everything:

[image: Sieve of Eratosthenes]

(from Wikipedia)

Comment: If he's read that in an algorithm book, I imagine book mentions algorithm name :)

Answer (score 0):

The inner loop (inside `if(a[i])`) is executed for prime `i`s only. I.e., for `i` equal to 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, ... And for single `i`, this loop has approximately `N/i` iterations. Thus, we have `N/2 + N/3 + N/5 + N/7 + N/11 + ...` iterations overall.