# Efficiency of Sieve of Eratosthenes algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, performance, primes, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I am trying to understand the "Sieve of Eratosthenes". Here is my algorithm (code below), and a list of features that I cannot understand (in order).

1. Why is `i * i` more efficient than `i * 2`? Yes, I can understand it would be less iterations, therefore more efficient, but then doesn't it skip some numbers (for example `i = 9` `=>` `j = 81` `skips 18 27 36 ...`)?
2. On Wikipedia I found that space complexity is equal to `O(n)` and that's understandable; whatever number we enter it creates an array of the size entered, but time complexity here is where things get confusing. I found this notation `O(n(logn)(loglogn))` -- what is that? According to my understanding we have 2 full iterations and 1 partial iteration, therefore `O(n^2 * logn)`.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  cout << "Enter number:" << endl;

  int arrSize;
  cin >> arrSize;

  bool primesArr[arrSize];
  primesArr[0] = false;
  for (int i = 1; i < arrSize; i++) primesArr[i] = true;

  for (int i = 2; i < arrSize; i++)

    if (primesArr[i - 1]) {
      cout << i << endl;
   /* for (int j = i * 2; j < arrSize; j += i) less efficient */
      for (int j = i * i; j < arrSize; j += i)
        primesArr[j - 1] = false;
    }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: VLA not a good idea in C++. Big size VLA a different problem altogether. Prefer a container.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Time complexity of Sieve of Eratosthenes algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2582732/time-complexity-of-sieve-of-eratosthenes-algorithm)

Comment: All multiples of the numbers smaller than `i` have already been eliminated in the previous iterations. Thus, `i * i` is the smallest multiple of `i` that hasn't been eliminated yet. (Write down the numbers from 1 to 100 on paper and execute the algorithm by hand to see it.)

Comment: As for the `i * i` question, it doesn't skip anything, because every number less than `i^2` is either prime or has a prime factor less than `i` and has therefore already been marked at a previous step.

Comment: "According to my understanding we have 2 full iterations and 1 partial iteration, therefore O(n^2 * logn)" complexity is difficult to calculate, especially in not trivial cases, how do you come up with O(n^2*logn)?

Answer (score 7):

> Why i * i more efficient than i * 2? Yes, I can understand it would be less iteration, therefore more efficiency, but then doesn't it skip some numbers (for example i = 9 => j = 81 skip 18 27 36 ...)?

You are referring to

```
for (int j = i * i; j < arrSize; j += i)
```

Note that `i * i` is the **initial** value for the loop counter `j`. So the values of `j` greater than `i * i` will all be marked off. The values which we skip from `i * 2` to `i * i` have already been marked off during previous iterations. Let's think about the first few:

When `i == 2`, we mark off all multiples of 2 (2, 4, 6, 8, etc.). When `i == 3`, if we start `j = 3 * 2 = 6` then we will mark off 6 again before reaching 9, 12, 15, etc. Since 6 is a multiple of 2 and was already marked off, we can skip straight to `3 * 3 == 9`.

When we reach `i == 5` and if we start at `j == 5 * 2 == 10`, then we will mark off 10, which was already taken care of since it is a multiple of 2, 15 which is a multiple of 3, and 20 which is also a multiple of 2 before we finally reach 25 which is not a multiple of any primer less than 5.

> time complexity here is where things get confusing. I found this notation O(n(logn)(loglogn)) -- what is that? According to my understanding we have 2 full iterations and 1 partial iteration, therefore O(n^2 * logn).

Your analysis reaches correct result that this algorithm is `O(n^2 * logn)`. [A more detailed analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes#Computational_analysis) can prove a tighter upper bound as `O(n(logn)(loglogn))`. Note that `O(n(logn)(loglogn))` is a subset of `O(n^2 * logn)`.

Answer (score 3):

> Why i * i more efficient than i * 2? Doesn't it skip some numbers?

No it doesn't because smaller multiple of `i` (For example 18, 27 etc in your case are covered while running loop for `i = 2`, `i = 3` etc)

Every number can be represented as unique prime factorization. If `i` is a prime number, any multiple of `i` greater than `i` and smaller than `i * i` would be multiple of one or more primes smaller than `i`.

> nasty notation `O(n(logn)(loglogn))`

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2582732/time-complexity-of-sieve-of-eratosthenes-algorithm)
Number of operations are 1/2 + 1/3 + 1/5 + 1/7 ... = n log log n
If you count bit operations, since you're dealing with numbers up to n, they have about log n bits, which is where the factor of log n comes in, giving O(n log n log log n) bit operations.