# C++ complexity of algorithm?

Tags: c++, algorithm, big-o

I wrote the following code:

```
class Solution {
public:
    int countPrimes(int n) {
        if (n==0 || n==1)
            return 0;
        int counter=n-2;
        vector<bool> res(n,true);
        for (int i=2;i<=sqrt(n)+1;++i)
        {
            if (res[i]==false)
                continue;
            for (int j=i*i;j<n;j+=i)
            {
                if (res[j]==true)
                {
                    --counter;
                    res[j]=false;
                }
            }
        }
        return counter;
    }
};
```

but couldn't find its complexity, the inner loop according to my calculations runs `n/2 + n/3 + ... + n/sqrt(n)`

Comment: Small note, does anyone know the name of the algorithm I used? I forgot it

Comment: what is your best guess so far? You need to apply the simplification on your formula and obtain a close formula

Comment: Seems like `Sieve of eratosthenes`. This should help in understanding the complexity: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2582732/time-complexity-of-sieve-of-eratosthenes-algorithm

Comment: @KunalKukreja not the same problem

Comment: @AlessandroTeruzzi I already wrote it but can't simplify it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Time complexity of Sieve of Eratosthenes algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2582732/time-complexity-of-sieve-of-eratosthenes-algorithm)

Answer (score 2):

Ok, let try to get the sum from your formula first (I am going to use your convention naming the variables):

[image]

Now, please note that n is a constant in the sum, so it can be moved outside the summary.

[image]

Now, we have one part which is linear and one part that we still need to estimate, but if you look closely it is very similar to the harmonic series, indeed for n that goes to infinity is the harmonic series - 1.

The grow rate of it is well know ln(n) + 1.(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)

So, complexity of the algorithm is n*ln(n).

**Update**

The Beta answer has the correct result (using the correct starting point), I will leave the above answer because the procedure remain the same and the answer, IMHO, it is still useful.

Answer (score 0):

*"...The inner loop according to my calculations runs n/2 + n/3 + ... + n/sqrt(n)"*

Ah, be careful with that ellipsis. It actually runs

```
n/2 + n/3 + n/5 + n/7 + n/11 + ... + n/sqrt(n)
```

This is not `n` times the harmonic series, this is `n` times the sum of the reciprocals of the primes, [a sum which grows as log(log(greatest denominator))](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_of_the_sum_of_the_reciprocals_of_the_primes).

So the complexity of the algorithm is O(n log log(n)).