# Time complexity

Tags: c++, data-structures, time-complexity

This question is for revision purposes from a past exam paper
I just want to know if I am on the right track

```
1. int i=1;
2. while (i <= n) {
3.   for (int j=1; j<10; j++)
4.     sum++;
5.   i++;
6. }
7. for( int j = 1; j <= n; j++ )
8.   for( int k = 1; k <= n; k=k*2 )
9.      sum++;
```

> 1.) How many times is statement 4 executed?
>   A. O(n)
>   B. O(n^2)
>   C. O(log n)
>   D. O(n log n)
>   E. none of the
>   above

Here I chose A

> 2.) How many times is statement 9 executed?
>  A. O(n)
>  B. O(n^2)
>  C. O(log n)
>  D. O(n log n)
>  E. none of the above

Because of line 8 (k=k*2) I chose C

> 3.) What is the running time of the entire code fragment?
>  A.
>   O(n)
>  B. O(n^2)
>  C. O(log n)
>  D. O(n log n)

Since O(n)+O(logn)=O(n) so I chose A

Comment: @Neil: Why do you think so? (Presumably this is not the entirety of the exam paper of course.)

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: probably because big-O is neither a quantity ("how many times is ...?") nor a duration ("what is the running time of ...?"). Far better would be the more accurate "what is the time complexity of ...?".

Comment: @paxdiablo: It is perfectly accurate to say "the number of times statement 4 is executed is O(n)". That is, the quantity/function 10n is O(n). (An entirely different matter is that perhaps the paper should have asked for Theta, or asked for smallest correct O(.), but that is forgivable depending on the level of the course.)

Comment: @Neil: I don't agree. It's important to teach programmers to recognize complexity of things they write, though this is somewhat trivial.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: Well, it kind of implicitly asks for *smallest correct* big-O; any bigger, though formally correct, answers wouldn't be accepted. In this case it could be asking for Theta, but for more complex cases it's usually not defined (it's not defined for anything where average case big-O is different from worst case big-O).

Comment: @Jan: We more or less agree (the question is ok and it's kind of implicit what's meant, though more precision would be nice). But note that O, Ω, and Theta are merely mathematical notation used to describe the asymptotic growth of any function; they have nothing to do with algorithms by themselves, and which you use to describe the running time of algorithms is orthogonal to whether you're analysing worst-, best- or average-case. (See e.g. [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960424/w/1960493#1960493).) So you could use Theta for either average- or worst-case complexity just fine.

Comment: @Neil The only problem I see with the question is its formulation.  "How many times?" cannot be answered using big-O; the question should be "What is the complexity?"  For the rest, it's a very good question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your answer 1 is correct, it's inside a loop controlled only by `n`.

Answer 2 is incorrect. It *would* be `O(log n)` if line 7 did not exist but, because line 7 is forcing lines 8 and 9 to run multiple times dependent on `n`, the answer is `O(n log n)`.

Answer 3 is the correct *reasoning* but suffers from the fact answer 2 was wrong. `O(n) + O(n log n)` simplifies down to `O(n log n)`.

So the answers are `A`, `D` and `D`.

Comment: @Annita: If this answer helped you, you can "accept" it by clicking on the tick mark beside it.

Comment: The comments under the line are wrong.  Big-O says nothing about time; it specifies the asymptotic complexity, generally in terms of some specific operation.  In that sense, it's closer to "how many times a piece of code is run" than it is to anything involving runtime (which also depends on things like locality---big-O always assumes that any give operation is constant time, where as memory access varies enormously depending on cache).

Comment: @James, the parenthesised "for time complexity" makes it clear that we're talking about time here.

Comment: @paxdiablo Except that big-O doesn't address time issues directly.  You can't analyze time issues using big-O.

Comment: I'm sure that's news to the vast majority of people who _do_ use it so :-) I agree that it's vastly more complicated than most realise but, in the context of this question, I believe what I said is correct. But, to be safe, I'l remove the offending section, especially since it has no real bearing on the question itself.

Answer (score 2):

I dont know how the questions where formulated, but if the wording is like you say, your examiner didnt know the right definition of big O (at least when he expects the "right" answers) – as "Big O functions include smaller". So something that executes as a function of n in f(n) = 10 n which is linear is also in O(n), O(n^2), O(n log n). 
If one asks for the "smallest" possible, your answers would be

1. Statement 4 is executed 10 n times, so A
2. Statement 9 is executed n*log n times, so D
3. Here it is executed the sum of both, n + n*log n so (here you lost an *n), so D would be the right.

So if multiple answers were possible and it was just asked for how much it is executed, the right answers would be

1. A,B,D
2. B,D
3. B,D

Comment: The *n* log *n* answer in question 2 is D, not C.

Comment: Yes already fixed it, misread the letter in the questions.

Comment: Each and every tutor and examiner I've met always implicitly meant *smallest correct* big-O when they talked/asked about big-O of something unless they needed to use the property that if function is O(something) than it's also O(something larger).

Comment: @Jan Hudec: For informal talk or some tutoring this might be ok, but for an exam one should be precise. And the definition is there quite clear, and all professor I have met were in their exams so correct and precise, to formulate so everybody know how the question was meant. How should the student know, that it was not the intention of the teacher to check also if he know that O(something) subset of O(something larger) - so all he could rely on is the wording of the question and answer it according to the definition.

Answer (score 1):

Ans 1: A ie. O(n) as the statement 4 would be executed 10*n times.

Ans 2: D ie. O(nlog(n)) as the statement 9 would be executed n*log(n) times.

Ans 3: D as the overall complexity [O(n) + O(nlog(n))] would be n*log(n).