# Looping through files in a folder and comparing it's name with a string in a field in a recordset

Tags: arrays, vba, ms-access

I am trying to find if my item images are linked correctly with full location string in a field on my table.
The following code works but the loop is not going through all the files. Can I use a `array` or a `collection` to hold the file names before comparing it to the  `rs1.Fileds("itemImage").Value`? If so, how do I go by? Any help even a direction would be highly welcome.

```
Private Sub btnFileName_Click()
Dim folderName As String
Dim FLibrary As Object
Dim FFolder As Object
Dim FFile As Object
Dim FFiles As Object
Dim strBackEndPath As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim rs1 As DAO.Recordset
Dim strFile As String
Dim strItemNo As String

Set rs1 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT ItemNo FROM tblDonatedItems")

strBackEndPath = CurrentDb.TableDefs("tblDonatedItems").Connect

i = InStrRev(strBackEndPath, "=") + 1
strBackEndPath = Mid(Left(strBackEndPath, InStrRev(strBackEndPath, "\")), i) + "ItemImages"
folderName = strBackEndPath

Set FLibrary = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set FFolder = FLibrary.GetFolder(folderName)
Set FFiles = FFolder.Files

strItemNo = rs1.Fields("ItemNo").Value

rs1.MoveFirst 
For Each FFile In FFiles
        Do While Not rs1.EOF                    
        If InStr(FFile.Name, strItemNo) Then
        Debug.Print FFile.Name & " , " & rs1.Fields("ItemNo").Value
        End If
        rs1.MoveNext
        Loop
Next FFile

Set FLibrary = Nothing
Set FFolder = Nothing
Set FFile = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Note: to step-debug your code, see [How to debug VBA code](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
For Each FFile In FFile
```

That makes no sense, you have the same variable here twice. So in the second run, `FFile` has been overwritten and is no longer a collection, hence the error.

You need

```
Dim FFiles As Object
Dim FFile As Object

Set FFiles = FFolder.Files

For Each FFile In FFiles
    Debug.Print FFile.Name
    ' etc
```

---

Well, your original question wasn't about performance. You have a double loop over records and files, so it's [O(n^2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27750064/algorithms-in-on2-vs-on), with a few hundreds of each it will be slow.

I suggest:

- A single loop over the folder files, that writes them into a (temp) table.
- An INNER JOIN of Items and temp table will show all matches.
- A LEFT JOIN / RIGHT JOIN with "is null" condition on the outer side will show all mismatches. You can use the "Find Unmatched" query wizard to get started.

You have a database, use it. And it will be fast too!

Comment: this would work if I am only interested in the file names. In my case, I am comparing the file name to to a variable string stored in a table.

Comment: Which you can do. With the change you now get FFile.Name for all files in the folder, in the loop.

Comment: I not sure if I understand, I have implemented the code as suggested. The loop happens but the file names remain constant. Please see updated code.

Comment: `Set FFile = FFolder.Files` is still wrong (must be FFiles).

Comment: That was a typo, issue still persists, I have notice a slow behaviour.

Comment: thank you so much for your kind direction. I have updated the code slightly and the performance issue has been minimised. Please see edit. I will think about your latest suggestion. In the mean time, is it even possible to some how hold the file names in an `array` and use the `array index` to compare it to `rs1.Fields("ItemImage").Value`?

Comment: Sure you can, and you'll find examples on the net. But why write more code than necessary?

Comment: thank you. I have created a table which temporarily stores the file names and added a column to my table for the file path bound to the image control. Your suggestion works just fine. But last week, supervisor said he prefers it if the table does not change at all so this morning, I started pulling out my hair one by one.