# Time complexity of nested loop with two different parameter

Tags: algorithm

How to work out the time complexity of this algorithm, both O() and Ω().

[image]
This nested loop is different from the common nested loop analysis, because m and n are independent such that |A| = n ≥ |B| = m.

What I am thinking is for each iteration, it will run O(1) time.

For the times of iteration (line 3 and line 4), it should be

m + (m − 1) + ... + 1 + (n - m) = O(m^2 + n)

Therefore, the time of this algorithm should be O(m^2 + n) and so is Ω.

However, the solution tells me it should be O(mn) and Ω(mn). I cannot figure it out how to get that answer.

Answer (score 1):

A quite terse explanation of [Can Berk Güder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1960428/2361308)

> O denotes an upper bound, but this bound might or might not be tight.
>
> Ω denotes a lower bound, but this bound might or might not be tight.

In your case, we don't consider the specific values (possible loops) there will be, but just in mathematical perspective, it's `O(mn)` and `Ω(mn)` since there is a `n` outer loop and `m` inner loop.

And a more straightforward definition in [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity) perhaps shed more light on your puzzle.

> Since an algorithm's running time may vary among different inputs of the same size, one commonly considers **the worst-case** time complexity, which is the maximum amount of time required for inputs of a given size. **Less common**, and usually specified explicitly, is the **average-case** complexity, which is the average of the time taken on inputs of a given size (this makes sense because there are only a finite number of possible inputs of a given size).