# An algorithm worst case O(n²) is better than a Ω(n log n) worst case?

Tags: c

An algorithm is *Ω (n log n)* then its better than *O(n²)* right?

Comment: The difference between Big O notation and Big Ω notation is that Big O is used to describe the worst case running time for an algorithm. But, Big Ω notation, on the other hand, is used to describe the best case running time for a given algorithm.  So the worst case for an algorithm with Ω (n log n) might be anything at all.

Comment: This is like asking, is paying >= $10 for option A is better than paying <= $15 for option B? Well, option A might really cost $1,000 and option B might really cost only $1.

Comment: You know the best possible running time  *Ω (n log n)* and the worst possible running time of the *O(n²)* algorithm.  You really have no way of comparing the two.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah That is wrong, big O can be used for best, worst or average case and so can big Ω. Please see [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960424/what-is-the-difference-between-o-%CE%A9-and-%CE%98)

Comment: @kaya3 I don't see how.  O(x) is the upper bound (the worst it can do) and Ω(x) is the lower bound (the best it can do).

Comment: @JerryJeremiah, worst, average and best input is orthogonal to the notation used. You can say that worst cast is bounded from below using `Ω` or that it's bounded from above using `O`. Or that it's bounded from both below and above using `Θ`.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah You are conflating "upper bound" with "worst case" and "lower bound" with "best case", but those are entirely different concepts.

Comment: If you don’t see how “upper bound” is different from “worst case”, I’ll blow your mind: if the worst case of an algorithm is linear, then the worst-case complexity of the algorithm is a O(n), which is also a O(n²). It is even a O(exp(exp(exp(n))).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `f(n) = Ω(g(n))` (see *note*) means that the running time `f` is bounded **from below** by `g` asymptotically ([see wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann%E2%80%93Landau_notations)). In other words, when `n → ∞`, `|f(n)| ≥ C ⋅ |g(n)|` (where `C` is some constant factor).

A worst-case complexity of `Ω(n log n)` means that the worst case of your algorithm runs **not faster (but possibly slower)** than `n log n`. It doesn't say anything about the upper bound, that's what `O` notation is for: if the worst-case complexity is a `O(n²)`, then your algorithm in worst case runs **not slower (but possibly faster)** than `n²`. The worst-case complexity of an algorithm can very well be `Ω(n log n)` and a `O(n²)` at the same time. These are different information (a lower and an upper bound).

All of this says nothing about the complexity of the best case, nor or the average case. Again you can use both `Ω` and `O` notations to describe these running times.

---

*Note:* the notation with `=` is misleading, as its right-hand side is *not* a function, but a class of functions; it would be better written `f ∈ Ω(g)`, but tradition has decided otherwise.

Comment: Can I say that the worst case algorithm Ω(n log n) is ***much better*** than O(n²)?

Comment: **No**, please carefully read the wiki article and comments. Say, your exact running time in worst case is `f(n)`.  `Ω(n log n)` means that for `n → ∞`  `n log n < f(n)`.  For all you know, f(n) can be n³ and the Ω bound will still be valid.